# Fastest way to find a big list of strings in a big data table in r

Tags: r

I have a list of around 15.000 user id's,

```
> head(ID_data)
[1] "A01Y" "AC43" "BBN5" "JK45" "NT66" "WC44"
```

and a table with 3 columns and around 100.000 rows as a data.table:

```
> head(USER_data)
              V1                    V2                 V3
1:             0                  John               John
2:          A01Y        Martin 3311290               
3: Peter Johnson            Peter JK45                  x 
4:             1        wc44@email.com     wc44@email.com         
5:            NA                     x          
6:        419223    Christian 21221140     ac43@email.com
```

I want to know the row index of rows that contain a user id somewhere in one of the 3 columns.

In the example above, the code should find row 2, 3, 4 and 6, since they contain  "A01Y", "JK45", "WC44" and "AC43" somewhere in one or more of the 3 columns.

The main problem is the big amount of data.

I have tried pasting "|" between the ID's and use grep to search for "A01Y|JK45" etc.:

```
toMatch <- paste(ID_data,collapse="|")
V1.matches <- grep(toMatch, USER_data$V1, ignore.case=TRUE)
V2.matches <- grep(toMatch, USER_data$V2, ignore.case=TRUE)
V3.matches <- grep(toMatch, USER_data$V3, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

but grep can only take a search pattern of around 2.500 ID's, so I would have to go through the ID's in blocks of size 2500. This takes around 15 minutes to compute.

I have also tried using strapplyc, which can take a search pattern of around 9.999 ID's.

Is there a faster way to find the row indices?

I was thinking of using sqldf() and do something like

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM USER_data, ID_data WHERE USER_data LIKE '%'+ID_data+'%'")
```

but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: have you looked at the `stringi` package? `stri_match`, `stri_locate` (et al) are vectorized over `str` and `pattern.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I haven't, I will give it a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fast enough, but I've done it before with many rows and IDs. It took me some time, but no need to process IDs in blocks.

```
# list of ids
IDs = c("A01Y", "AC43", "BBN5", "JK45", "NT66", "WC44")

# example dataframe
dt =  data.frame(V1 = c("Christian 21223456","x", "wc44@email.com"),
                 V2 = c("0 John","1 wc44@email.com",  "wc44@email.com"),
                 V3 = c("1","0","A01Y Martin 3311290"))

dt

#                   V1               V2                  V3
# 1 Christian 21223456           0 John                   1
# 2                  x 1 wc44@email.com                   0
# 3     wc44@email.com   wc44@email.com A01Y Martin 3311290


# combine row elements in one big string
dt_rows = apply(dt, 1, function(x) paste(x,collapse = " "))

# update to lower case
IDs = tolower(IDs)
dt_rows = tolower(dt_rows)

# find in which row you have matches
sapply(IDs, grepl, dt_rows) 

#       a01y  ac43  bbn5  jk45  nt66  wc44
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE


# find which row id has a match (at least one match)
which(apply(sapply(IDs, grepl, dt_rows), 1, sum) >= 1) 

# [1] 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem of having to process the IDs in blocks, but as you said, this was slow and my initial solution using strapplyc in blocks of 9.999 IDs was actually faster.

Comment: Good. Useful comparison and nice finding for future reference.